# Comparing array element using Junit

Tags: java, junit

I have a two string array in java where I am comparing the whole array using `assertArrayEquals`.
example:

```
Expected:[CTSCAT, CTSSCH, PERSONS, ID, CTSCAT, CTSSCH, ORDERS, PERSONID, 1, 3, 3, FK_PERSONORDER, PK_PERSON, 7]

Actual:[CTSCAT, CTSSCH, PERSONS, ID, CTSCAT, CTSSCH, ORDERS, PERSONID, 1, 3, 3, FK_PERSONORDER, PK_PERSON, 7]
```

But know I want to compare some element of array instead of entire array. Like in same example I only want to check first two element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare with the help of **assertEquals**:

```
assertEquals(arr1[0],arr2[0]);
```

and so on..

Comment: I thought of writing a function where it can use assertEqual for the indexes but i thought their might be some other way for this.

Comment: You can try with assertThat clause too...You can convert your arrays into list and then try:


assertThat(list1, contains(list2.get(0),list2.get(1));

You can apply combinations further to that

Answer (score 0):

Try using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) library. It has very good support for arrays and its much more readable.

You can find the array example [here](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/ArrayAssertionsExamples.java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hamcrest matchers ([javadoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#arrayContaining(E...))):

```
assertThat(arr1, Matchers.arrayContaining(arr2));
```